# Invalid scope error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm trying to send bitcons using coinbase ruby gem but I'm having a hard time getting it to work. I'm authenticating like this:

```
c = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV["COINBASE_KEY"], api_secret: ENV["COINBASE_SECRET"])
ca = c.account(User.last.account.account_id)

ca.send(to: ENV["BITCOIN_ADDRESS"], amount: '0.0001', currency: 'BTC')
```

This is the error I'm getting back.

```
Coinbase::Wallet::InvalidScopeError: Api::BaseController::InvalidScopeError
```

To be clear, the API key has the required permission set in the dashboard. what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Ruby gem uses API v2 which requires v2 scope, `wallet:transactions:send` instead of v1's `send`. Can you check that you have this enabled?

Comment: If you mean that if I've enabled this at the backend, yes I do have it enabled.

Comment: In that case I suggest that you inspect the expection payload, it might have more information